# jQuery. Скопировать ссылку и добавить в нужный блок

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скопировать ссылку из блока (блоков много) и вставить ее в этот же блок. Сейчас во все блоки вставляется ссылка из первого блока.

**html**

```
<div class="item">
   <a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
   <a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var lnk = $('.item').find('.link').attr('href');
$('.item').append('<a class="button" href="'+ lnk + '">Заказать</a>');
```

Comment: Откуда скопировать? не ясно ?

Comment: Скопировать ссылку из класса .link. Наверное нужно использовать .each, но не умею с ним работать пока, нужна помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У jQuery есть отличный метод .clone() который копирует (если нужно с обработчиками событий).

```
var items = $('.item'), 
    lnk = item.find('.link').clone(true);

lnk.appendTo(item);
```

Если надо пройтись по всем блокам и потом скопировать каждую ссылку в тот же блок в котором она была то:

```
var items = $('.item'); 

 items.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        lnk = $this.find('.link').clone(true);

    lnk.appendTo($this);

    //если привыкли к append то 
    $this.append(lnk);
 })
```

А если в какой-нибудь другой то по аналогии.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно, цикл по набору элементов, и в цикле вставляем `href` в нутрь самого тега.

```js
$('.link').each(function(i,elem) {
  $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
   <a class="link" href="Ссылка 1">Ссылка</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
   <a class="link" href="Ссылка 2">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще работающий код:

```
$('.item').each(function(id, elm){
  var href = $(elm).find('.link').attr('href');
  $(elm).append('<a class="button" href="'+ href + '">Заказать</a>');
});
```